# Как при профилировании в gprof получить файл gmon.out когда корректное завершение программы невозможно?

Tags: c++, gcc, профилирование

Осваиваю gprof. У меня есть многопоточное приложение, которое необходимо оптимизировать. В этом приложении 7 отсоединённых потоков в которых крутятся бесконечные циклы. Я так понимаю, что бы получить gmon.out просто запуска приложения недостаточно, надо его еще и завершить. Я попробовал кинуть ексепшн через 30 секунд после старта, но файл gmon.out так и не был сгенерировать. Как мне получить gmon.out когда нормальное завершения приложения невозможно? При этом если создать hello world то файл генерируется (т.е. всё работает).

Comment: 1) приложение надо исправить чтобы была возможность корректного завершения 2) отсоединенных потоков быть не должно

Comment: @VTT т.е. я должен обязательно дождаться завершения потоков через join, или достаточно просто не отсоединять их?

Comment: Если их не отсоединять и не вызывать join, то в деструкторе `std::thread` например будет вызван `std::terminate`.

Comment: @VTT это я понимаю, с имею в виду что во втором случае файл gmon.out сгенерирован не будет, так?

Comment: Отсутствие join - это практически гарантированное аварийное завершение приложения и профилирование (даже если какие-то результаты будут) теряет смысл.

Comment: Блин, получается надо перелопатить много кода ((. Спасибо за помошь.

Comment: @VTT Я ввёл атомарный флаг завершения всех циклов и сделал join всех потоков после которого я жду 3 секунды и делаю terun 0. Перед этим я дожидаюсь завершения всех асинхронных вызовов. Так же у меня используется асинхронный boost::asio поэтому я закрываю все сокеты и останавливаю все его сервисы. Но даже после всего этого я получаю terminate called without an active exception. Могу ли я как-то понять почему так происходит?

Comment: Поотлаживать отладчиком. По идее при вызове abort должна сработать точка останова.